# Сортировка массива, состоящего из массива

Tags: массивы, objective-c, сортировка

Здравствуйте есть массив вида:

```
(
    (
    1,
    "Hello"
),
    (
    2,
    "How are you"
),
    (
    3,
    "Bombaleylo"
)
)
```

Нужно его отсортировать не по 1,2,3 а по тексту.

Я пнимаю, что нужно использовать

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor;
sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"?????"
                                             ascending:YES];

NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];

NSArray *sortedArray = [messages sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

Но не знаю что писать в ?????, прошу помощи

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sortedArrayUsingDescriptors` здесь не годится, он предназначен для сортировки массива словарей. Вам здесь можно использовать `sortedArrayUsingComparator`:

```
NSarray *sortedArray =
  [messages sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(NSarray *a1, NSArray *a2) {
       NSString *s1 = a1[1];
       NSString *s2 = a2[1];
       return [s1 compare:s2];
     }];
```